# How to add a group pushbutton like this under QListWidget like this?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

I learn to write a simple Player use Qt.

I want ask, how to create a group pushbutton like this:

[image]

use `QGroupButton`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no QGroupButton class in Qt. There is a `QButtonGroup` class, but it doesn't provide any visual representation.

In your case you can put your buttons into a `QHBoxLayout` which has spacing set to 0 (`QLayout::setSpacing(int)`)

Comment: And there are `QToolButton`s on the picture I think.